# How can I call php function in AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form which calls a php function and returns converted currency when the button is submited. My need is to call this php function in ajax and return the results(results to be displayed in textfield results) without pressing the submit button. I want as the user types the amount he wishes to convert, the function is automatically called without pressing the submit button. Below is my form and php function:

```
  <form class="form-signin" action="" method="post">

        <h4 class="form-signin-heading"style="color:white;">Check Our Rates Here!</h4>
        <Strong style="color:white;">i have:</strong>
            <select class="form-control" name="from"id="from">
            <option value="<?php echo getcurrency();?>"><?php echo getcurrency();?></option>
            <option value="USD">American Dollar(USD)</option>
            <option value="GBP">Britsh Pound(GBP)</option>


        </select>
        <input type="text" name="amount"id="amount"class="form-control" Amount="Your email"required autofocus>
        <Strong style="color:white;">Reciver Gets:</strong>
           <select class="form-control" name="to"id="to" >
            <option value="USD">American Dollar(USD)</option>
            <option value="GBP">Britsh Pound(GBP)</option>
            <option value="UGX">uganda shillings (UGX)</option>
            <option value="KES">Kenya Shilling(KES)</option>
            <option value="EUR">Euro(EUR)</option>

        </select>
        <input class="form-control" id="results"name="results"value="<?php if(isset($_POST['amount'],$_POST['from'],$_POST['to'])){
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];
             $from = $_POST['from'];
             $to = $_POST['to'];

         $currency = currencyConverter($from,$to,$amount);
            echo $currency;


        }?>">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="submit"type="submit">Convert</button>

    </form>
```

and this is my php currency convert function

```
function currencyConverter($from,$to,$amount){
    $yql_base_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
    $yql_query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("'.$from.$to.'")';
    $yql_query_url = $yql_base_url . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query);
    $yql_query_url .= "&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
    $yql_session = file_get_contents($yql_query_url);
    $yql_json =  json_decode($yql_session,true);
    $currency_output = (float) $amount*$yql_json['query']['results']['rate']['Rate'];
    if($from=='AED'&&$to=='USD'){
        $aedtousd='4';
        $finalaedtousd = $currency_output-$aedtousd;
        return $finalaedtousd;  

    }else if($from=='USD'&&$to=='AED') {
        $aedtousd ='0.033';
        return $currency_output-$aedtousd;
    }else if($from=='AED'&&$to=='UGX'){
        $eadtougx ='18';
        return $currency_output-$eadtougx;
    }else{
        return $currency_output;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use javascript? Convert you function to javascript so you don't have to communicate with a server.

Comment: AJAX requires writing Javascript -- that's what the **J** stands for. There are many tutorials on AJAX, you need to read one, try to write the code, and then come back if you can't get it working.